# LinQ to xml, specifying a route that can be null at any point

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<b>
  <c>
     <z> Wally  </z>
     <w> whatever </w>  
  </c>
  <d>
     <z> anotherValue </z>
  </d>
  <e> idValue </e>
</b>


class Example {
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Suppose we have the above xml and class. Im trying to create an object from the xml using LinQ to Xml.

I could achieve this with something like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var root = doc.Root;

var anExample = new Example()
{
   Id = root.Element("e").Value,
   name = root.Element("c").Element("z").Value
};
```

So far so good, the problem is that 'c' and 'z' tags are optional. You could have no 'c' at all or 'c' without 'z'. 
Then I would find myself checking whether or not each of this tags are null in order to avoid calling the Element method and Value property on a null object.
I mean:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var root = doc.Root;

var anExample = new Example(){ Id = root.Element("e").Value };

var c = root.Element("c")

if(c != null) {
   var z = c.Element("z");
   if( z != null)
    anExample.name = z.Value;
}
```

And as the nested levels increase things get worst. I suppose there most be a better way to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [C# 6.0 null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) to ensure that all items in call chain are not null:

```
// C# 6 or higher:
string value = doc.Root?.Element("c")?.Element("z")?.Value;
```

The result of this expression will have a value if only all given elements exist, and will be `null` otherwise.

Another way is to use [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) extension methods from `System.Xml.XPath` namespace to find an element. It is more suitable if you use C# 6 or even older version since it looks nice without null-conditional operator:

```
// C# 6 or higher:
string value = doc.Root.XPathSelectElement("./c/z")?.Value;

// C# 5 or lower:
var element = doc.Root.XPathSelectElement("./c/z");
if (element != null)
{
    string value = element.Value;
}
```

The result will be the same since `XPathSelectElement` will return `null` if element does not exist.

Comment: Please note that this syntax is available since C# 6.0 (operator `?.`).

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Thank you for this nice correction! I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to avoid xpath and focus only on Linq to xml. The null conditional operator seems the best option to me.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to stay in the LINQ world of `IEnumerable` until the last possible moment.

This means using `Elements` instead of `Element` - this will return an empty sequence in the case the element is missing.

At the end, you can call `SingleOrDefault` to get the resulting element or null in the case one of the elements along the way was missing.

Note that there are [explicit conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit(v=vs.110).aspx) that can convert an element to various types - this can be useful when you need conversion to something other than `string` and can also handle the case where the element is null.

```
var name = (string) root.Elements("c").Elements("z").SingleOrDefault()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works great, but what if instead of a the value I want an attribute  of 'z' ? SingleOrDefault.Attribute("attr")   would throw an error.

Comment: @ricky as well as `Elements` there's is also and `Attributes`. So `root.Elements("c").Attributes("z").SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: I didn't know that. Another solution could be:    (<proper_casting_if_needed>)root.Elements("c").Elements("z").SingleOrDefault()?.Attribute("anAttr").Value